# Google Play Billing 5.0 relations between Products, Subscriptions and Base Plans

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, android-billing, play-billing-library

I have an app currently using Google Play Billing 4.0. I'd like to migrate from 4.0 to 5.0.

Previously I had different subscriptions distinct by billing period (e.g.: monthly, weekly yearly). I understand from this [What's new in Google Play](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/05/whats-new-in-google-play.html) that the new Plans system addresses this, and kind of groups subscriptions by a common factor (here, time).

In my app, I show users a list of subscriptions with their prices and respective billing periods. In the new system, is a **Product** analogous to a **Subscription**? If it is, will I get all the *Plans* of a **Subscription** inside a **Product**? Also what will happen to a ***Purchase Token*** if a user changes *Plan* but not a **Subscription**? Also, from the purchase object in `queryPurcahses`, can I know which plan a user is currently using?